# Play Framework WebSocket Example - only one real source (without fake generator)

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka-stream, playframework-2.6

I need some help with some modification of https://github.com/playframework/play-java-websocket-example.
This example based on own `Source` for given Stock ID. Every `Source` generate new stock value in some time interval:

```
public Source<StockUpdate, NotUsed> update() {
    return source.throttle(1, duration, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
            .map(sq -> new StockUpdate(sq.symbol, sq.price));
}
```

---

The example in much part is what I need (the "watch/unwatch" stocks idea) so I want to use it in very similiar way but I don't want to fake stock quote time interval generator in my app because I'm connected to **real, one stock exchange source**. 
I read messages (in other part of my app) via `java.io.InputStream` and, for now, I put them in `java.util.Queue` (`java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`) via `queue.offer(message)` and now **I want to get it somehow from Stock.update()** (however I don't know it's best place).

So far I got know that I could use for example `Source.queue(BUFFER_LENGTH, OverflowStrategy.backpressure())`, but it doesn't have any reference to (my) queue.
I also know that I could use `Source.queue(BUFFER_LENGTH, OverflowStrategy.backpressure()).to(...).run(...).offer(...)` but unfortunatelly I don't know how to connect it in `UserActor.addStock(Stock)` with `Flow`, `UniqueKillSwitch`, etc.

Maybe someone needed modifications like me and could give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

> So far I got know that I could use for example Source.queue(BUFFER_LENGTH, OverflowStrategy.backpressure()), but it doesn't have any reference to (my) queue

You could change your code so it uses the `Source.queue` instead of the `java.util.Queue`. Alternatively you could have a thread to read from your queue and push it to the `Source.queue`.

Comment: But how to put (offer) into queue in `MyClass.java` to the `Source.queue` from `Stock.java`? Source.queue(...) returns `Source<Object, SourceQueueWithComplete<Object>>`